# How to Remove quotation mark with object data type from a column in Python and convert to float

Tags: python, object, data-cleaning, datacolumn

Customer id    -----           object

ValueError: could not convert string to float: "'5769842393258'"

df["Customer id"]  = df["Customer id"] .replace('"', '', regex=True)

df["Customer id"] = np.array(df["Customer id"],dtype=float)

Answer (score 0):

Try...

`df["Customer id"] = float(df["Customer id"])`

Answer (score 0):

You might simply use `.str.strip` method as follows

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':["'123'","'456'","'789'"]})
df['Xnum'] = df['X'].str.strip("'").astype(float)
print(df)
```

output

```
       X   Xnum
0  '123'  123.0
1  '456'  456.0
2  '789'  789.0
```

Explanation: `.str` allow using [String Methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) on strings which are inside `pandas.Series` (column of `pandas.DataFrame`)